# A System Running only one program

Tags: linux, windows, system, boot

I visited an organization and saw their custom invoice system. when they start their system then it only opens their software nothing else. I was not able to see whether it was windows,linux.

at boot up it was showing loading modules ..etc. but after start up it showed directly their software , nohthing else. They can not access anything other than that software.

I am curious to know how is this possible ? Kindly answer.

Comment: This is sometimes called _kiosk mode_. In Linux it is relatively easy. In Windows it is more difficult because there are some pieces of the system, hot-keys, etc. that are difficult to disable, but there are third party software that manages that.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Linux this can be done easily: Use the `init=` parameter in your efi/bootloader to specific the level 0 binary to execute.